# Removing special characters from text using pyspark rdd

Tags: python, pyspark, count, rdd

I have a text file and I would like to count bigrams (2 successive letters within a word, not the various other characters) in it.

I have some code shown below but it does not replace those special characters.

```
special_chars = "!#$%^&()€[]”“’‘—,.?"
sentences = sc.textFile('/FileStore/tables/text_data.txt') \
    .glom() \
    .map(lambda x: "".join(x)) \
    .flatMap(lambda x: x.split("."))

#bigrams = sentences.map(lambda x: x.replace(',', '').replace('”', '').replace('—', '').replace('$', '').lower()) \ (this line works but it is limited use since more than 3 replace generate errors.)
bigrams = sentences.map(lambda x: x.replace(special_chars, '').lower()) \
    .flatMap(lambda x: x.split()) \
    .flatMap(lambda x: [((x[i],x[i+1]),1) for i in range (0,len(x)-1)])

freq_bigrams = bigrams.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y) \
    .map(lambda x: (x[1],x[0])) \
    .sortByKey(ascending=True)

freq_bigrams.take(5)

Out[81]: [(1, (',', '”')),
 (1, ('p', 'c')),
 (1, ('c', 's')),
 (1, ('l', 'g')),
 (1, ('o', 'x')),
 (1, ('a', '’')),
 (1, ('”', ')')),
 (1, ('2', ',')),
 (1, ('w', 'n')),
 (1, ('f', ','))]
```

Could anyone point out what is necessary action here?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out:

```
special_chars = ",!#$%^&()€[]''`~”—,.?" #removing special characters 
bigrams = sentences.map(lambda x: x.replace(special_chars, '').lower()) \
    .map(lambda x: x.lower().replace(',', ''))\
    .map(lambda x: x.lower().replace('”', ''))\
    .map(lambda x: x.lower().replace('’', ''))\
    .flatMap(lambda x: x.split()) \
    .flatMap(lambda x: [((x[i],x[i+1]),1) for i in range (0,len(x)-1)])

freq_bigrams = bigrams.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y) \
    .map(lambda x: (x[1],x[0])) \
    .sortByKey(ascending=True)
```